# Combobox inside another combobox

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word

Need help writing a code - I've developed a userform.

I need one combo box to show the main section of a letter:
"based on our determination HE/SHE is entitled to a refund"
"based on our determination HE/SHE is not entitled to a refund"

but I also need a combo box to select gender:
"HE"
"SHE"

so far I have:

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
With ComboBoxDecision
.AddItem "based on our determination HE/SHE is entitled to a refund"
.AddItem "based on our determination HE/SHE is not entitled to a refund"
End With
With ComboBoxGender
.AddItem "HE"
.AddItem "SHE"
End With
lbl_exit:
Exit sub
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonOk_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("Decision").Range.Text = ComboBoxDecision.Value
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Is there a way to do:

```
.AddItem "based on our determination "Whatever option was selected in ComboBoxGender" is entitled to a refund"
.AddItem "based on our determination "Whatever option was selected in ComboBoxGender" is not entitled to a refund"
```

Happy to supply any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to populate the 'Decision' combobox with the appropriate text each time the 'Gender' combobox changes. You'd do this by trapping the `ComboBoxGender_Change` event, like so:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxGender_Change()
    Dim gndr As String

    gndr = Me.ComboBoxGender.Text

    With Me.ComboBoxDecision
        .Clear
        .AddItem "based on our determination " & _
                 gndr & " is entitled to a refund"
        .AddItem "based on our determination " & _
                 gndr & " is not entitled to a refund"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ComboBoxGender
        .AddItem "HE"
        .AddItem "SHE"
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store multiple choices in different columns of the same combo box. Depending upon the choice of gender you then hide one or the other of the columns. In code that would look as follows.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Arr(1, 1) As String

    ' Column, item:
    Arr(1, 0) = "Based on our determination she is not entitled to a refund"
    Arr(0, 0) = Replace(Arr(1, 0), "not", "")
    Arr(1, 1) = Replace(Arr(1, 0), "she", "he")
    Arr(0, 1) = Replace(Arr(1, 1), "not", "")
    With CbxDecision
        .List = Arr
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With

    With CbxGender
        .List = Split("He She")
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub CbxGender_Change()
    ' set the list width for 1st and 2nd column
    ' one of them must always be 0 (= hidden)
    CbxDecision.ColumnWidths = Split("0pt;90pt|90pt;0pt", "|")(CbxGender.ListIndex)
End Sub
```